# In Chrome 3d rotating a div occurs behind an adjacent div, but occurs in front in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of divs set up with display: inline-block. When I 3d-rotate them along the y-axis, part of the div leaves the bounds of the resting div so it overlaps with the other adjacent divs.

In firefox it works perfectly, the part of the div closest in the viewers perspective is taller and is visible on top of the adjacent divs.

But in Chrome, the bottom edge of the div is behind the div below. Am i missing something?

HTML

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <div style="background-color:red;height:162px;width:343px"> front</div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div style="background-color:red;height:162px;width:343px"> back</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <div style="background-color:blue;height:162px;width:343px"> front</div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div style="background-color:blue;height:162px;width:343px"> back</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    transform: perspective(1000px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    display:inline-block;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 343px;
    height: 162px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

   position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p3dcasn/1/)

Mousing over the divs will slowly rotate so you can see the overlap

Answer (score 0):

1. Give all the Divs a separate id. eg- red , blue , green
2. Use javascript to change z-index on hover.
   Here is an example : (do it for all 3)

`document.getElementById('blue').hover.style.zIndex = document.getElementById('red').style.zIndex + document.getElementById('green').style.zIndex + "1";`

- This will set the z-index of div on hover to 1 more than the z-index of other 2 Divs.
- I am sure there is a more efficient way. Try to experiment with it, may be make a function that on hover on any element of a specific class would make its z-index greater than all. But this will work too.

**edit: Don't forget to make their position relative**